# Electric outlet causes a light to go off (but can be flipped back on)

Tags: electrical

I have a very weird situation here... I have an outlet and a switch on the same wall. The ceiling light controlled by the switch works fine on its own. However, when the switch is on, if I try to plug in anything (I tried two different LED lamps) into the outlet, the ceiling light will turn off immediately (the switch is still “on”), but the lamp connected to the outlet works fine and the breaker also doesn’t trip. Now comes the weirdest thing - I can turn the switch off, then on, and then the ceiling light is on again.

What could have caused this? Note that the ceiling light is an integrated LED light. My suspicion is that “plugging a load to the outlet” triggered whatever protection mechanism the ceiling light has. Is my guess correct? Or could this be a more serious issue? Thanks!

Comment: My first guess is a bad backstab connection on the outlet.  I'm assuming this all worked correctly in the past, and the problem "just started" for no apparent reason.  If that's true, then the first thing to eliminate is flaky connections, such as back-stab connectors on outlets and switches. Less likely but possible-bad connections made with an inferior grade wire nut.

Comment: Is this "light switch" in fact a motion sensor, dimmer, lighted switch, smart switch or anything that uses power *itself*?   Who did the wiring on this circuit and when?

Comment: Thanks for the comment! The light switch is a regular switch, nothing fancy. We recently purchased the house and moved in... not sure if it was an issue before.